# SPFx "Command Set" that displays a dialog box or panel containing a "people picker" control

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, command-set

I'm new to working with SPFx extensions.

Requirement is create a SPFx "Command Set", that on click displays some sort of dialog box or panel containing a "people picker" control within it. I've looked up several references but all had code samples of adding people picker in SPFx webpart and not within a command set extension.

Appreciate any guidance on how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to add people picker on SPFx "Command Set". You can extend '[BaseDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-dialog/basedialog?view=sp-typescript-latest)' class instead of using the default '[Dialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-dialog/dialog?view=sp-typescript-latest)'.

For more details, please Take a reference of below docs:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/using-custom-dialogs-with-spfx
- https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/master/samples/react-command-directions/README.md